# addition of two empiric probability density functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, empirical-processes

If I have two empiric probability density functions (i.e. I can generate n points then form a histogram then normalize it) what is their "sum", I think [convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263974/sums-of-two-probability-density-functions) but I'm not sure. If yes then how to get $P_c$ = $P_a$ + $P_b$ ? where $P_a$, $P_b$ and $P_c$ are empiric probability density functions and $P_a$, $P_b$ are given?
Second part of the question: If I have Pc and Pa can I get Pb?